# Adding Role Property to the existing MVC 5 web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication, user-roles

I have created a project based on the sample posted on the official ASP.NET site: [MVC 5 with 2FA, email confirmation, password reset SMS,Two-Factor Authentication](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MVC-5-with-2FA-email-8f26d952). On the other hand, although there is a separate table for Roles, I have no idea how to integrate such a kind of control which meet best my requirements. I just want to create some roles and assign them to the users. After a user login to the system, I want to check his roles and let them to reach the enabled actions for this role. How can I make such a kind of integration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Authorize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute to specify the role(s) allowed to access a controller or action.

```
[Authorize(Roles="user, admin, another")]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But, I know this and I need a sample that give an idea for me to proceed on the right way. Any idea?

Comment: Thats not really a question for stack overflow. You can add roles to users and check if the user has a role using the code I supplied.

Comment: What about the first part (... add roles to users ...)?